# Azure Powershell website cmdlet's not working correctly on server

Tags: powershell, azure, windows-server-2012, azure-web-app-service

I am setting up deployment of an azure website on a build server running Server 2012.

I first tried to deploy from my local machine using the following steps (and it worked):

- Install Azure Powershell using WPI
- Use `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile` command and `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` to get access to my Azure websites etc from powershell
- Run command `Get-AzureWebsites` and I see a list of my websites
- Run `Publish-AzureWebsiteProject` to publish my package to the website

All the above works. However, when I follow exactly the same steps on my server, when I get to the `Get-AzureWebsites` step, I get nothing back. As a follow on from this, when I try and run the publish command, I get a "website does not exist" error.

If I run the `Get-AzureAccount` and `Get-AzureSubscription` commands, I get back the correct account / subscriptions.

I have no idea what is going on?!

Comment: are there are more than one subscription accessed from that server. can you check if this subscription is the default subscription?

Comment: Aha no the subscription I want isnt the default, how do I set the default subscription?

Comment: Select-AzureSubscription -Default 'subscription name'

Comment: You are a genius my friend, after hours and hours last night you have sorted it for me immediately :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if there are more than one azure subscriptions on that server. If there are more, make sure that the subscription that you need is set as default.
Use the command:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Default 'subscription name'
```

... to set the default subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Azure command is  `Get-AzureWebsite` not `Get-AzureWebsites`.